# Как отобразить имя экземпляра класса в окне watches в PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

Пытаюсь понять, как сделать так, чтобы имя экземпляра класса или какой-то другой его атрибут отображаться в переменных при дебаге. Использую PyCharm, но подозреваю конкретная IDE значения не имеет.

Например, вот так сделано для экземпляра класса в openpyxl (в кавычках имя экземпляра):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Найти ничего подобного не удалось, возможно потому что я не очень правильно формирую запрос.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это достигается через метод класса `__repr__`. Например, вот так [он выглядит](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/src/8953233f5af287d9cdf3dae34e437e76bea5bd59/openpyxl/workbook/child.py#lines-51) в `openpyxl`:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return '<{0} "{1}">'.format(self.__class__.__name__, self.title)
```

В кавычках, кстати, пишется название листа в книге Excel.